# How to do a Django list in list query

Tags: python, django, list, django-models, django-queryset

I have a list of lists filter items as this:
`[['3aa', '1ss', '2bb'], ['4aa', '5bb'], ['3nn', '9mm', '6cc']]`

My database table has a field with a field(category) holding a list as value: `['4aa', '5bb']`
How can I query to fetch items whose category is in the filter list?

Something like:

```
Table.objects.filter(category__in=[['3aa', '1ss', '2bb'], ['4aa', '5bb'], ['3nn', '9mm', '6cc']])

Model:
Class Table(…):
   category = models.jsonfield()
```

Comment: Show the exact model code instead of describing it. You can't get good suggestions on queries if we don't know what your database structure looks like.

Comment: I think the question is clear enough for suggestions without pasting the model.

Comment: depends on whether they are using an ArrayField or have an intermediate model or other construction for the categories. I can't tell from the question itself, and the answer is different for each.

Comment: Have you tried this [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75628093/17562044) Answer given by me?

Comment: @SunderamDubey yeah, I have. Alombaros is the best option.

Comment: Ah you found the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does exact lookup work ? (`Table.objects.filter(category=['3aa', '1ss', '2bb'])`)
If so you can use Q objects

```
q_conditions = Q()
for categories in categories_list:
    q_conditions |= Q(category=categories)

Table.objects.filter(q_conditions)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably take the list of lists and flatten them into one list.

```
# flatten list of lists
ls = [['3aa', '1ss', '2bb'], ['4aa', '5bb'], ['3nn', '9mm', '6cc']]
 
# iterate through list of lists in a nested loop
flat_ls = []
for i in ls:
    for j in i:
        flat_ls.append(j)

Table.objects.filter(category__in=flat_ls)
```

Comment: Thanks but this will require I do another for loop through the flatten list for a query ``` contains```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should flatten the filter list into a single list so that you can pass it to the `__in` lookup, like so:

```py
filter_list = [['3aa', '1ss', '2bb'], ['4aa', '5bb'], ['3nn', '9mm', '6cc']]
flat_filtered_list = [item for sublist in filter_list for item in sublist]

result = Table.objects.filter(category__in=flat_filtered_list)
```